# How to pass a List of a class into model of ajax post call MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a model class like below:

```
public class clsUser
{
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public String username { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }
    public List<ContactNumbers> Cnumbers{ get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to send ajax request with above model. i have tried to do same by using the following code:

```
  var dd =
   {

   "FirstName": "ABC",
   "username": "abc123",
   "password": "abc@123",
   "Cnumbers[0].Home":"0987654321",
   "Cnumbers[1].Company":"7654321"
   }

    var objInsertUser= JSON.stringify(dd);
    var URLValue = "http://localhost:47083/api/TestAPI/insertUser";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URLValue,
        data: objInsertUser,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }

    });
```

But this always sending "Cnumbers" as null. i am not getting why..

If i am doing in wrong way could experts tell me the correct way..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the ajax attribute dataType: 'json' ?

Comment: Your array will bind fine if you remove `contentType: "application/json",`and use `data: dd` (dont stringfy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create proper JSON. You need to create an array for `Cnumbers`

```
var dd = {
    "FirstName": "ABC",
    "username": "abc123",
    "password": "abc@123",
    "Cnumbers": [{
        "Home": "0987654321"
    }, {
        "Company": "7654321"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Add the stringify wrapper and inline the url around data: JSON.Stringify(objInsertUser), saves the extra lines.

Comment: @wadry, Yes, you are correct but thats not the problem area thus ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely lies in `var objInsertUser= JSON.stringify(dd);`. Your object is already JSON, so there's no need to stringfy it. `data: dd,` should be sufficient. When you Stringify already existing JSON you end up with default values for the parameters, and all non-primitives are null by default.

Also, [as noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36774772/1015495), your JSON is incorrect. Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "*I know, I'll use JSON. Now you have two problems*" XD. So, in summary: use correct JSON, and don't `JSON.Stringify` existing JSON.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.